# How to list user based on their roles in Symfony2 + Doctrine effectively

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have done this with this code

```
$users = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT tu FROM UserBundle:User tu')
            ->getResult();

$result = array();

foreach($users as $user){
if($user->hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOMER'))
    $result[] = $user;
}

return $this->render('XBundle:Order:index.html.twig', 
          array('users' => $result));
```

But what is the simple way to achieve this same result ?

Thanks.

Update, additional info:

Our main problem is that user roles have a hierarchical structure.

So ROLE_EDITOR will automatically have ROLE_WRITER if I defined ROLE_WRITER under ROLE_EDITOR.

Thus I can't just use simple query, I think I also have to utilize security context component.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your schema, but I guess you could do an `INNER JOIN` and put your condition in the `ON` clause. Read [this article about the query builder](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/query-builder.html) to figure out how to build your query.

Comment: My structure is same with FOSUserBundle, this roles is just serialized array saved in one column in user table. Our main problem is that user roles have hierarchy structure. So ROLE_EDITOR will automatically has ROLE_WRITER if I defined ROLE_WRITER under ROLE_EDITOR. Thus I can't just use simple query but I think I have to utilize security context component also.

Comment: I guess you could try using a LIKE on the serialized data.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the hierarchy roles is **stored in security context** not in serialized data. Although an user only have **ROLE_EDITOR** in serialized data, but he also granted to access ROLE_WRITER. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine collections also have a `filter` method that takes a `Closure` as an argument.

Comment: and greg0ire We can't do this because it just compare plain text roles, whereas in symfony2, roles getter implementation was like this           
public function hasRole($role)
{
    return in_array(strtoupper($role), $this->getRoles(), true);
}        
public function getRoles()
{
        $roles = $this->roles;

        foreach ($this->getGroups() as $group) {
            $roles = array_merge($roles, $group->getRoles());
        }

        // we need to make sure to have at least one role
        $roles[] = static::ROLE_DEFAULT;

        return array_unique($roles);
}